# Есть ли приложения для чтения базы данных (расширение .db) на Андроид?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, поиск-программ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, приложение на Андроид для чтения базы данных с расширением .db, если существуют такие вообще...

Comment: под расширением .db может скрываться какой угодно формат, включая обычный текст.

Comment: Разве? Обычный текст это база данных?

Comment: я не говорил, что обычный текст это база данных. Я говорил, что расширение .db ничего не говорит о формате файла. Почему вы думаете, что там база данных?

Comment: открой файл блокнотом и посмотри первые буквы

Comment: DB – это файл базы данных SQLite, которая часто используется на мобильных устройствах, таких как Android, IOS и Windows Phone. Если написать об этом расширении, то поисковик тут же выдаст это "определение")) Поэтому, я думаю, что там база данных. По поводу блокнота не знаю, я там не проверял, так как устройство просит загрузить приложение для чтения такого формата файлов)

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн самый очевидный вариант: в Google Play в поиске ввести SQLite, и я сейчас там вижу как минимум 3 варианта, похожих на то что нужно.

Comment: Вы правы, я так делал, но, при загрузке нескольких приложений, они отказывались открывать базу данных. Причина до сих пор мне неизвестна. На данный момент я уже смог найти более-менее нормальное

Comment: Понятие "расширение", как вы его понимаете, существует только на Windows. Ни iOS, ни Android на расширения не обращают никакого внимания. Файлы с данными SQLite встречаются и с названиями `mydata.sqlite`.

Comment: Ясно, на будущее запомню...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего внутри sqlite. Программ много https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sqlite&c=apps

Если не откроет, то может быть dbf - тоже есть пара программ.

Comment: Спасибо, смог найти тот, который мне нужен))